# Resize inner control width when vertical scrollbar shows up

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have:

```
<DockPanel>
  <!-- Left Panel -->
  <LocalViews:MyView1 DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="250" />
```

and in `MyView1`

```
<DockPanel>
 <Button ...

 <ListBox>
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <GroupBox>
        <!-- stuff here -->
        ...
    </DataTemplate>
```

I don't know if that's relevant, but I have completely overridden the default `ListItem` style, because I want it to look like an `ItemTemplate`, but with support of `SelectedItem`:

```
<Style TargetType="ListBox" x:Key="XXX" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBox}}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Vertical scrollbar doesn't show by default (good) and when I resize the window and decrease the available height, it shows up (also good). Problem is, the vertical scrollbar causes a horizontal scrollbar. I don't want that.

[image]

[image]

What's driving me crazy is that in the Designer (VS) it looks fine:

[image]

I have seen solutions where an additional space is left on the side of the inner control, to allow for the scrollbar to appear and another solution where the scrollbar is visible at all times so it doesn't 'jump out'. I don't like either.

My question is - what style do I apply to the listbox item template so that when the vertical scrollbar shows up, the item will resize its width to fit the now shrinked available horizontal space?

Comment: What's the rest of the ItemsControl look like, are you scrolling with an external ScrollViewer?

Comment: @Joe - I have updated the question

Comment: That's much more useful! See edit to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you sizing your window(Or parent container)? Without any more information to go on, there's only a small case where both scroll bars appear like you describe - where the width of container hosting the scroll viewer is between the minimum width of your content, and the minimum width of the content plus the width of the scroll bar itself.

Normally, the vertical scroll bar appears no problem when the height decreases below the minimum height. Similarly with the horizontal and width. It's only when these two coincide where they "trigger" each other. Here's all three cases, see how it's only a 10by10 (ish) pixel size where the triggering occurs? This is pretty unlikely:

[image]

The only reason I can see this being a problem is if it's the default state. The chances of the user happening to have their window size at the correct point for this to be a regular occurance is pretty minimal. If it does happen, say at 'key' resolutions and your content is fixed - change the width of the internals by a few pixels until it doesn't.

The only other time this would occur regularly is if you are sizing your window based on the content, say with `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"` (or SizeToContent="Width"). This tells your window to size itself to the minimum possible width. The problem is, this is always in the case where adding a scroll bar will cause this behavior.

You could start your window maximized, or at a sensible resolution that's fixed. Or create some sensible logic/behavior to adjust the starting window size a little bigger than `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"` provides.

---

**Edit**

I see you set the width of the parent container as an absolute 250. Try setting this to 270 (The default width of a scrollbar on windows 10 is 17px).

Are you setting the content of the ListBox manually to 250 width somewhere as well? If the contents and the container are both 250, when the scrollbar appears there's nothing else for it to do but horizontal scroll.

As this doesn't happen with an identical structure on my end:

[image]

The natural conclusion is it's the content of the group box. Try commenting this out to confirm. Something isn't playing well with it's layout!

Comment: Regardless of the width I give it, the behavior is absolutely the same.

Comment: How are you setting the width of the items in the template group box?

Comment: I don't. They resize according to the available space. By the way I have updated the question to show that in the Designer the ListBox looks OK.

Comment: I notice your group box doesn't display any horizontal size settings, usually this means it defaults to HorizontalAlignment=Left - meaning it hugs the left and doesn't stretch across - unless the content is sized the same.

Comment: If you set the designer Width=250 at the top of the user control MyView1 it's still the okay? I hate tracking down stuff like this!

Comment: Down to `d:DesignWidth="230"` the Vertical scroll doesn't cause a horizontal scroll in the designer. But that should be fine, because I give the listbox at least 290 (now) width. I can't track either what causes the horizontal to show ...

Comment: That's really wierd. When I come across issues like this, I find it best to start blocking out areas until I can narrow down where the problem is. With the exact same layout structure I don't see this issue unless I filddle with the content of the GroupBox. Comment out the group box content (so it's just the empy group boxes) and see if the problem still occurs.

Comment: Thank you, with your advice about narrowing down the issue I have tracked it down to a `MahAppsControls:MetroProgressBar` deep inside my user control.

Comment: Amazingly a `ProgressBar` with value larger than `99` (but less or equal to `100`) would cause this issue on my machine. Can you reproduce?

Comment: Yep, I'm seeing that too. I did try replicate with progress bars but couldn't get it to happen - but I was trying with 50. What an odd little bug in MahApps,

Comment: Even funnier, it's not in MahApps but in the WPF out-of-box `ProgressBar` ... I have replaced my MahApps:ProgressBar controls with the regular ones and I am still seeing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
<DockPanel>
  <Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" />
  <ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
           ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
           HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <GroupBox>
          ...Your Content Here...
        </GroupBox>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox>
</DockPanel>
```

I can't see, what your ListBox-Style should do for you, especially that you don't refer to the style in your Sample snippet... However...

Your ListboxItems should fit the horizontal space now, with or without the vertical scrollbar